# Dropwizard Hibernate Session in Jackson Deserializer

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

I'm using a Dropwizard server with Hibernate but now I ran into the issue that I have an object returned to my REST API as JSON object or as number, the id of the object.

My custom deserializer is looking like this:

```
public class ItemDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Item> {
    @Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(p);

        Item item = null;
        String value = node.toString();

        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(value)) {
            ItemDao dao = Globals.getCommunicationWrapper().getFactory().getItemDao();
            item = dao.fetch(Long.parseLong(value));
        } else {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            item = mapper.treeToValue(node, Item.class);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

I am using a static object as a quick and dirty hack which is initialized with the `UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory` to have a hibernate session. Is there any way to initialize the deserializer with a hibernate session so I can instanciate the DAO there? Or access a non static dao from somewhere else? Maybe by passing something to the deserializers constructor?